# Adding font files to a Web Application

Tags: css, asp.net, fonts, webforms, webfonts

I'm working on ASP.NET web forms application .I'm using Visual Studio 2019. I wanted add two new fonts to the application and I added using below way and it working as expected . I have checked changes with Firefox , Google Chrome and New Edge and it's working fine.I just added one file type to each font as below.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'TT Commons';
    src:url('./Fonts/TTCommons/TTCommons2.woff2') format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Hind';
    src: url('./Fonts/Hind/Hind-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

But I saw many examples in web as below (Which containing many file types for one font)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'font-name';
    src: url('font-name.eot');
    src: url('font-name?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('font-name.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font-name.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font-name.svg#font-name') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I want to know adding one type is enough or do I need to add every type and I'm Using Git do I need to convert these files to binary before committing. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different font file formats are supported by different versions of browsers, the latest being `woff2`.

For maximum backwards compatibility, you should use the second example you showed with many font file formats.

You can check https://caniuse.com/woff2 to see the various browser support. If the shown level of support is acceptable, you can use just `woff2`.